# Question unfairly closed

Tags: discussion

I recently posted [this question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/69551/why-is-that-states-to-the-northern-side-of-india-speak-more-hindi-than-southern), I got the following set of three comments. Which I quote and try to understand one by one

> India is nine times the size of Germany, and roughly the size of Europe west of a line from Szczecin (Stettin) to Venice; an area which is home to the major languages of French, Portuguese, Spanish, German, and Italian as well as a host of minor languages. On what basis do you expect a heavily populated area that large and diverse to NOT have many languages?

I have no idea why this comment was written. I do not think no where in the post I said I expected Indian state only to have one language. I simply asked, why northern side speaks more than southern.

> This question really needs some initial research (at least), and the use 'Hindi' needs some clarification. Try looking at Hindi language. –

There are of course places where this is discussed, eg this [quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Hindi-spoken-mostly-in-the-northern-and-middle-India) thread but it doesn't have any trust worthy reference. The purpose of me asking in this site is to get more reputed answers which are sourced.

> Are you asking specifically about speaking Hindi at all, or are you asking about native languages? The chart you posted seems to include second language speakers, but it is not clear from your question whether you are including those. –

I simply asked, why more fraction of people speak Hindi in northern state than other. I never put an additional condition if it is as native language or not. So, I don't understand why the commentors are stuck up on this.

I hope my question can get reviewed and reopened.

Comment: Second comment asks for 'what have you researched so far?', giving a link-hint for a source to be expected to consult. First guess: That link provides some explanation & another map to compare to 'yours'. L1-native speakers form the heartland of Hindi (the belt) and yours shows how useful knowing Hindi including as 2nd language is 'to get by' in India. _"Is."_ & 'Seems quite simple', like the 1st comment: Dutch and Polish people tend to speak German as well, Spanish do so much less—distance to contact/practicality. What your _historical_ inquiry on this is remains unclear to me.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't close it or comment, so if I were you I'd be more interested in an answer from one of the people who did.

However, I saw the question, and as someone who has an interest and a fair bit of researched knowledge on the subject of world linguistic history, would honestly like to try to answer it. Unfortunately, I literally don't understand what you're asking.

At present, the best answer I can give to a simple "why" question like that is **"Why not?"**

In other words, why *wouldn't* things be that way? They have to be *some* way, right? What's at all odd about it? Perhaps if you can edit the question text to answer my "Why not?" question, you'd have a more answerable H.SE question on your hands?

---

Speculation section -
I *think* you are trying to do one of two things here:

Guess 1: You meant to be asking something along the lines of "How did the modern distribution of Hindi come to be?" (which honestly demands a novel, not an answer here), or perhaps "Why did Hindi become dominant over so much of the Subcontinent, but never got any further south?" (not a bad question there IMHO)

Guess 2: You've actually got a bit of an agenda, and any answers that call back into the current consensus history/linguistics/archeology picture of Hindi being an Indo-European language that migrated in with its speakers from the Eurasian heartland of that language family, will be jumped on and argued. In fact the question was perhaps a prompt for inducing this exact argument, rather than a serious question.

I'm sorry if Guess 2 is insulting, but we really get people like that here, and as a new user, for all we know you're one of those. Questions that are likely fodder for such people tend to get extra scrutiny, and tend to be put on hold much more quickly.

Comment: Not sure of Guess-2 exactly means but maybe it does relate to answer of-1. And if an OP actually disagrees with answer, is that a problem actually?  

I guess it's close to guess-1 what I had in mind.

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational - Well, in that case what I said in guess 1 applies. The second narrower question formulation I put there would IMHO be a good question here, assuming that's what you want to know. You'd have to ask other users if they think that'd be good enough to get reopen votes (as a mod, I don't get to participate in votes). I think it should, but I'm wrong a lot. :-)